# unity creates too many objects for unknown reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I created this code and for some reason unity duplicates backGround infinitely, I can't debug with the debugger because there are too many objects. isActivated starts as false.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{

    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "MainCamera" && isActivated == false)
    {
        isActivated = true;
        Rigidbody2D backgroundclone = (Rigidbody2D) Instantiate(backGround, new Vector3(46, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Rigidbody2D backgroundclone1 = (Rigidbody2D)Instantiate(backGround, new Vector3(-46, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Rigidbody2D backgroundclone2 = (Rigidbody2D)Instantiate(backGround, new Vector3(0, 21, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Rigidbody2D backgroundclone3 = (Rigidbody2D)Instantiate(backGround, new Vector3(0, -21, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is triggered every frame, but the if statement is supposed to stop it right?

Comment: No, MainCamera is only in the first background, but OnTriggerEnter2D() attached to all backgrounds

Comment: But there isn't a Maincamera to trigger the cloning

Comment: If this script is run on every background clone then the isActivated will be false and therefore will trigger the script to clone again.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure this script doesn't appear on you clones.